# Redirect URL based on condition Apache Httpd.conf

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting, jboss, httpd.conf

I am using Apache web server "httpd-2.4.25-win64-VC14" which is integrated with JBoss. The Port redirect is working properly. Now i want to replace URL based on some condition let's say if URL contains `'Mobile'` then i want to replace it with `'Mobile/web'` and forward it.

For this I am using `<Directory>` tag enclosed within `<VirtualHost>` tag. Now most the online references I am finding are having URL's in front of  tag such as `'var/www/example'` but I want to redirect based on `localhost`  as I am running Jboss locallly.

So how should I write the  tag contents , i tried with the below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>          
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (manage)
        RewriteRule ^Mobile http://%{HTTP_HOST}/Mobile/web=%1 [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Like `http://localhost:8081/Mobile/register` should be replaced with `http://localhost:8081/Mobile/web/register`
Please  Suggest

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to redirect only when the Query String contains a word "manage":

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (manage)
```

If you want to redirect when the Query String doesn't contain a certain word you can use a pattern like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (!manage)
```

And the rewrite rule like this one:

```
 RewriteRule ^Mobile /Mobile/web/register [NC,L,QSA]
```

QSA may be helpful here:

> Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query
>   string created in the rewrite target.

This solution will pass all of the Query String parameters and redirect from *http://localhost:8081/Mobile/register?arg1=value1&arg2=value2* to *http://localhost:8081/Mobile/web/register?arg1=value1&arg2=value2*.